# NSDateFormatter getting wrong milliseconds differences when comparing two dates in Xcode 6.3.2

Tags: ios, objective-c, date

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSString *dateStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[cachedPostArray objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"date_time"]];

NSDate *dtTime1 = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateStr];            
double timeInMS1 =(long) (floor([[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]) * 1000 );
double timeInMS2 =(long) (floor([dtTime1 timeIntervalSince1970]) * 1000 );

NSString *diffTimestamp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",timeInMS1 - timeInMS2];
```

I am passing dateStr = 2015-06-18 18:37:57 compare with current date time.
Always getting difference 0 in milliseconds.

Comment: What are values for `timeInMS1` and `timeInMS2`?

Comment: What does `[[cachedPostArray objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"date_time"]` return?

Comment: and why are you formatting the string as a string with the only parameter beeing a string? just temove the `stringWithFormat`!

Comment: @luk2302 Or simply: NSString *dateStr = cachedPostArray[0][@"date_time"];

Comment: @zaph that is what i meant, yes.

Comment: Please accept my answer by clicking the checkmark next to it if it helped you fixing your bug!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you `floor` the values to early:

```
double timeInMS1 =(long) (floor([[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]) * 1000 );
double timeInMS2 =(long) (floor([dtTime1 timeIntervalSince1970]) * 1000 );
```

should actually be without the `floor` or without the cast and the `floor` later (after the multiply with 1000):

```
double timeInMS1 = floor([[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000 );
double timeInMS2 = floor([dtTime1 timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000 );
```

What you are currently do is get the seconds and the milliseconds after the decimal point, then you `removing` the milliseconds, **then** you multiply by a 1000. That is too late.

Or, as rmaddy correctly suggested, use long in the first place:

```
long timeInMS1 = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000;
long timeInMS2 = [dtTime1 timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000;
```

Comment: Since the goal is to get integer milliseconds, don't bother with `floor` at all and change `timeInMS1` and `timeInMS2` to `long` instead of `double`.

Comment: @rmaddy right... edited to include that, does that fir your suggestion?

Comment: No need for the casts. The compiler will automatically cast the `double` values to `long`.

Comment: but it will warn you, dont like warnings!?

Comment: I suppose that depends on your compiler settings. I always compile clean (I treat warnings as errors) but I don't get warnings about such an implicit conversion (at least I don't think I do). I'll have to check. The explicit cast should be used if needed.